# Using MPU6050 accelerometer/gyroscope module

Tags: arduino, accelerometer, microcontroller, robotics, gyroscope

I'm testing my [MPU6050 module](http://www.ebay.com/itm/MPU-6050-Module-3-Axis-Gyroscope-Acce-lerometer-for-Arduino-Power-supply-3v-5v-/281033263573?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item416ee349d5) with [Arduino Mega](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardMega). I found Jeff Rowberg has written a library for this. I tried with [this example](https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib/blob/master/Arduino/MPU6050/Examples/MPU6050_DMP6/MPU6050_DMP6.ino) provided by him. But the Arduino IDE gives a large number of errors when trying to verify the sketch.

I've already installed Jeffs library. *(following image shows the library content)*

[image]

This is the error I'm getting:

```
In file included from C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MPU6050/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:42,
                 from sketch_dec08a.cpp:50:
C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MPU6050/MPU6050.h:792: warning: only initialized variables can be placed into program memory area
In file included from sketch_dec08a.cpp:50:
C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MPU6050/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:89: warning: only initialized variables can be placed into program memory area
C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MPU6050/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:89: error: conflicting declaration 'const prog_uchar dmpMemory [1929]'
C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MPU6050/MPU6050.h:792: error: 'dmpMemory' has a previous declaration as 'prog_uchar dmpMemory [1929]'
C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MPU6050/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:229: warning: only initialized variables can be placed into program memory area
C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MPU6050/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:271: warning: only initialized variables can be placed into program memory area
C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MPU6050/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:271: error: conflicting declaration 'const prog_uchar dmpUpdates [47]'
C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MPU6050/MPU6050.h:931: error: 'dmpUpdates' has a previous declaration as 'uint8_t dmpUpdates [29][9]'
C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MPU6050/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:281: error: no 'uint8_t MPU6050::dmpInitialize()' member function declared in class 'MPU6050'
C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MPU6050/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:506: error: no 'bool MPU6050::dmpPacketAvailable()' member function declared in class 'MPU6050'
C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MPU6050/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:533: error: no 'uint8_t MPU6050::dmpGetAccel(int32_t*, const uint8_t*)' member function declared in class 'MPU6050'
C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MPU6050/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:541: error: no 'uint8_t MPU6050::dmpGetAccel(int16_t*, const uint8_t*)' member function declared in class 'MPU6050'
C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MPU6050/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:549: error: no 'uint8_t MPU6050::dmpGetAccel(VectorInt16*, const uint8_t*)' member function declared in class 'MPU6050'
C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MPU6050/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:557: error: no 'uint8_t MPU6050::dmpGetQuaternion(int32_t*, const uint8_t*)' member function declared in class 'MPU6050'
C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MPU6050/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:566: error: no 'uint8_t MPU6050::dmpGetQuaternion(int16_t*, const uint8_t*)' member function declared in class 'MPU6050'
C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MPU6050/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:575: error: no 'uint8_t MPU6050::dmpGetQuaternion(Quaternion*, const uint8_t*)' member function declared in class 'MPU6050'
C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MPU6050/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:590: error: no 'uint8_t MPU6050::dmpGetGyro(int32_t*, const uint8_t*)' member function declared in class 'MPU6050'
C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MPU6050/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:598: error: no 'uint8_t MPU6050::dmpGetGyro(int16_t*, const uint8_t*)' member function declared in class 'MPU6050'
C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MPU6050/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:608: error: no 'uint8_t MPU6050::dmpGetLinearAccel(VectorInt16*, VectorInt16*, VectorFloat*)' member function declared in class 'MPU6050'
C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MPU6050/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:616: error: no 'uint8_t MPU6050::dmpGetLinearAccelInWorld(VectorInt16*, VectorInt16*, Quaternion*)' member function declared in class 'MPU6050'
C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MPU6050/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:628: error: no 'uint8_t MPU6050::dmpGetGravity(VectorFloat*, Quaternion*)' member function declared in class 'MPU6050'
C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MPU6050/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:639: error: no 'uint8_t MPU6050::dmpGetEuler(float*, Quaternion*)' member function declared in class 'MPU6050'
C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MPU6050/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:645: error: no 'uint8_t MPU6050::dmpGetYawPitchRoll(float*, Quaternion*, VectorFloat*)' member function declared in class 'MPU6050'
C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MPU6050/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:658: error: no 'uint8_t MPU6050::dmpProcessFIFOPacket(const unsigned char*)' member function declared in class 'MPU6050'
C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MPU6050/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:668: error: no 'uint8_t MPU6050::dmpReadAndProcessFIFOPacket(uint8_t, uint8_t*)' member function declared in class 'MPU6050'
C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MPU6050/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h:693: error: no 'uint16_t MPU6050::dmpGetFIFOPacketSize()' member function declared in class 'MPU6050'
sketch_dec08a.cpp: In function 'void setup()':
sketch_dec08a.cpp:177: warning: only initialized variables can be placed into program memory area
sketch_dec08a.cpp:181: warning: only initialized variables can be placed into program memory area
sketch_dec08a.cpp:182: warning: only initialized variables can be placed into program memory area
sketch_dec08a.cpp:182: warning: only initialized variables can be placed into program memory area
sketch_dec08a.cpp:185: warning: only initialized variables can be placed into program memory area
sketch_dec08a.cpp:191: warning: only initialized variables can be placed into program memory area
sketch_dec08a:187: error: 'class MPU6050' has no member named 'dmpInitialize'
sketch_dec08a.cpp:197: warning: only initialized variables can be placed into program memory area
sketch_dec08a.cpp:201: warning: only initialized variables can be placed into program memory area
sketch_dec08a:198: error: 'class MPU6050' has no member named 'getIntStatus'
sketch_dec08a.cpp:206: warning: only initialized variables can be placed into program memory area
sketch_dec08a:205: error: 'class MPU6050' has no member named 'dmpGetFIFOPacketSize'
sketch_dec08a.cpp:216: warning: only initialized variables can be placed into program memory area
sketch_dec08a.cpp:218: warning: only initialized variables can be placed into program memory area
sketch_dec08a.cpp: In function 'void loop()':
sketch_dec08a:246: error: 'class MPU6050' has no member named 'getIntStatus'
sketch_dec08a.cpp:260: warning: only initialized variables can be placed into program memory area
sketch_dec08a:263: error: 'class MPU6050' has no member named 'getFIFOBytes'
```

How do I overcome this?

I've been trying very hard to use this device to get acceleration/gyroscope values. But still no success.

---

**EDIT**

This is what I get when trying to compile (verify).

[image]

Comment: Seems like a compiler problem. Can you try that and get back?
I've used the mpu6050 and jeff rowberg's code, had lots of problems but not that one...

Comment: @lifesayko Well, as you asked, I've removed the whole library and re-created it from the files [here](https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib/tree/master/Arduino/MPU6050). The same example comes as a library example. I loaded it and tried. But still, the verification fails. I don't know what to do. It says,  **'class MPU6050' has no member named 'dmpInitialize'**. I've uploaded a screen shot too. Please see in the edited post. Thanks!

Comment: Looking at the link you posted there isn't a dmpInitialize, there is an initialize however maybe try that. I'm not familiar with that module but maybe the 'dmp' prefix is some sort of debug version in a different library. Sorry I see the extra version in the .h file, but looks like it depends on particular conditional defines.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Just gave a try, its not working either. But I think the original call is right. Jeff himself has written the code. (BTW, _dmp_ is not for debugging, it means _Digital Motion Processor_)

Comment: Okay, seems then like you're missing some DEFs. Basically, Jeff's library has some "add-on" parts which you may or may not need (for example, you can grab all the raw data without the dmp). Make sure you're including all the headers needed, and that you declare the DEFs you need (including MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h)

Comment: @lifesayko From the two examples, the example that gives raw values _(MPU6050_raw)_ works. But I need meaningful values. That's why I'm trying to make the other example work _(the one we are talking about, MPU6050_DMP6)_, hoping it'll provide meaningful values. 
If you have a code that give meaningful values, can you post it? I'm new to these digital gyro/acceleratometer modules (and a bit to Arduino too :D ). I need to get those values to be used with an aerial robot. The raw values are really awkward. Especially I can't imagine how to get the gyro reading (angle) from the raw ones..

Answer (score 4):

The MPU6050_DMP6 example provided by Jeff works for me. From your compile error, it seems that you've included MPU6050.h, instead of MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h. Make sure you include the correct one.

If you look at the [library code](https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib/blob/master/Arduino/MPU6050/MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h), you'll notice that the .dmp_*_*_ methods are not implemented in the MPU6050.cpp file, but in the MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h file. If this doesn't solve it, post your code.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried exactly with [this code](https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib/blob/master/Arduino/MPU6050/Examples/MPU6050_DMP6/MPU6050_DMP6.ino). There can't be any wrong I guess. I wonder whether my library is not properly established. Please see the first image in my question, I've included a screenshot there. But as I see, there's no any problem either. Anyhow, compiler still gives the same error..

Comment: @Anubis I had a similar problem and solved it by using the code here : https://www.electronicwings.com/arduino/mpu6050-interfacing-with-arduino-uno  . Remove any other mpu6050 library.

Answer (score 2):

try putting jeffs i2c .cpp and .h files into the same folder as the mpu6050 library files i found that this then worked for me, sorry if this is a litte late but hopefully helpful :P

Comment: The issue was solved after upgrading the arduino ide to the latest. Thanks anyway..

Comment: ^ Should post your solution as answer

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and it turned out I was including both 
MPU6050.h and MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h.  I commented out MPU6050.h and it now compiles fine.  Seems that the former was overriding the latter.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the compile problem by putting I2Cdev.cpp and I2C.h in the MPU6050 library folder. (Mind: these are the *dev* files). These are Jeff's libraries and can be found at [GitHub](https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib/tree/master/Arduino/I2Cdev)